# Issues passing File object to function

Tags: file, rust, io

I am trying to read and write files passing around a `File` object. It keeps giving me errors saying the file descriptor is not valid.

Does this have something to do with how Rust works in memory? Like if do below it does not work, saying `write_all` method not found in file. I also tried declaring it as `std::fs::File` but not working.

What's the way around this? I could just pass the filename but opening and closing the file constantly seems weird.

```
fn write_to_file(fd: File, data: &str){
    fd.write_all(data.as_bytes()).expect("error writing");

}

fn main(){
   let filename = "testing.txt";
   let mut fd = File::create(filename).expect("error creating file");
   write_to_file(fd,"text to write");
}
```

Comment: Please include the error you're getting.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the [`File::write_all()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.write_all) function of `std::fs::File` you will need the `std::io::Write` trait in scope (in the docs you will also see
`use std::io::prelude::*;`). Apart from that the file must be mutable if you want to alter its content.

I guess this is what you want:

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Write;

fn write_to_file(fd: &mut File, data: &str){
    fd.write_all(data.as_bytes()).expect("error writing");

}

fn main(){
   let filename = "testing.txt";
   let mut fd = File::create(filename).expect("error creating file");
   write_to_file(&mut fd, "text to write");
}
```

And the [link to the Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ec6fd9c52d1cb903b7055427c134b5ce).

Comment: Ok thanks this explains it, in my main code i was opening the file with OpenOptions and using that as a File object so i tried a quick example code to pass a file object like in the code bove and it didnt work, but adding the mut and including the io crate worked

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use `fd` in two functions, but your code tells Rust to specifically forbid that, and limit `fd`'s existence to one function at a time.

Rust has a concept of *single ownership*, which is the default for non-copyable types like `File`.

When you have a function argument `fd: File`, this means the function will take over the exclusive ownership the `fd`.

`fd: &File` takes a temporary shared reference. It allows the same object to be accessed from multiple places.

`fd: &mut File` takes a temporary exclusive reference. It's a similar exclusivity guarantee to passing ownership, except that when scope of `&mut` ends, the ownership is automatically returned to the previous owner, instead of destroying the object.

So you need to pass a temporary reference to `write_to_file` (with `fd: &mut File`), instead of giving it `fd` forever (`fd: File`).